# Accessing a Hash within an Array that is within a hash by permaiters

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, json, hash

I am trying to get the name of the first goalscorer. The problem with this is that the data is in a Hash which is within an array in the below hash and then I need to test it to see if it is a goal or not.

Any ideas?

Data:

```
[
   {
      "id":1474387,
      "date":"2013-11-24 16:00:00",
      "competition_id":831975,
      "competition":"England Premier League",
      "group":"",
      "home_id":8344,
      "home":"Cardiff City",
      "homeshort":"Cardiff",
      "homepath":"cardiff-city",
      "away_id":10260,
      "away":"Manchester United",
      "awayshort":"Man Utd",
      "awaypath":"manchester-united",
      "status":"Finished",
      "halftime":[
         1,
         2
      ],
      "fulltime":[
         2,
         2
      ],
      "extratime":[
         0,
         0
      ],
      "penalties":[
         0,
         0
      ],
      "incidents":[
         {
            "id":2670186,
            "type":"Yellow",
            "goaltype":null,
            "team_id":10260,
            "team":"Manchester United",
            "teamshort":"Man Utd",
            "teampath":"manchester-united",
            "player_id":30829,
            "player":"Wayne Rooney",
            "playershort":"W. Rooney",
            "minute":8
         },
         {
            "id":2670226,
            "type":"Goal",
            "goaltype":"Regular goal",
            "team_id":10260,
            "team":"Manchester United",
            "teamshort":"Man Utd",
            "teampath":"manchester-united",
            "player_id":30829,
            "player":"Wayne Rooney",
            "playershort":"W. Rooney",
            "minute":15
         },
         {
            "id":2670320,
            "type":"Goal",
            "goaltype":"Regular goal",
            "team_id":8344,
            "team":"Cardiff City",
            "teamshort":"Cardiff",
            "teampath":"cardiff-city",
            "player_id":24157,
            "player":"Fraizer Campbell",
            "playershort":"F. Campbell",
            "minute":33
         },
         {
            "id":2670367,
            "type":"Goal",
            "goaltype":"Regular goal",
            "team_id":10260,
            "team":"Manchester United",
            "teamshort":"Man Utd",
            "teampath":"manchester-united",
            "player_id":32569,
            "player":"Patrice Evra",
            "playershort":"P. Evra",
            "minute":45
         },
         {
            "id":2670471,
            "type":"Yellow",
            "goaltype":null,
            "team_id":8344,
            "team":"Cardiff City",
            "teamshort":"Cardiff",
            "teampath":"cardiff-city",
            "player_id":176889,
            "player":"Steven Caulker",
            "playershort":"S. Caulker",
            "minute":51
         },
         {
            "id":2670485,
            "type":"Yellow",
            "goaltype":null,
            "team_id":8344,
            "team":"Cardiff City",
            "teamshort":"Cardiff",
            "teampath":"cardiff-city",
            "player_id":23806,
            "player":"Peter Whittingham",
            "playershort":"P. Whittingham",
            "minute":55
         },
         {
            "id":2670648,
            "type":"Yellow",
            "goaltype":null,
            "team_id":10260,
            "team":"Manchester United",
            "teamshort":"Man Utd",
            "teampath":"manchester-united",
            "player_id":160713,
            "player":"Tom Cleverley",
            "playershort":"T. Cleverley",
            "minute":87
         },
         {
            "id":2670676,
            "type":"Goal",
            "goaltype":"Regular goal",
            "team_id":8344,
            "team":"Cardiff City",
            "teamshort":"Cardiff",
            "teampath":"cardiff-city",
            "player_id":197910,
            "player":"Bo-Kyung Kim",
            "playershort":"BK. Kim",
            "minute":90
         },
         {
            "id":2670718,
            "type":"Yellow",
            "goaltype":null,
            "team_id":8344,
            "team":"Cardiff City",
            "teamshort":"Cardiff",
            "teampath":"cardiff-city",
            "player_id":159882,
            "player":"Kevin Theophile Catherine",
            "playershort":"K. Theophile Catherine",
            "minute":90
         },
         {
            "id":2670720,
            "type":"Yellow",
            "goaltype":null,
            "team_id":8344,
            "team":"Cardiff City",
            "teamshort":"Cardiff",
            "teampath":"cardiff-city",
            "player_id":197910,
            "player":"Bo-Kyung Kim",
            "playershort":"BK. Kim",
            "minute":90
         }
      ]
   }
]
```

Comment: You need to use the .each loop inside another loop I was going to show you but that code is very hard to read. Can you link the controller?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have the data for one match you can get the first goal scorer like this:

```
goal_incident = match['incidents'].detect{|i| i['type'] == 'Goal'}
if goal_incident
  puts "First goal scorer was #{goal_incident['playershort']}"
else
  puts "There were no goals :("
end
```

Your solution is ok but it is a little bit slower. When you use `select` ruby has to iterate through the whole array which is unnecessary if you're only interested in the first goal. When  you use `detect` the loop ends after the first goal is found.

Answer (score 0):

This is how I solved it in the end:

Any refactor ideas?

```
json.each do |result|
  score = result["fulltime"]
  goals = result['incidents'].select do |incidents|
    incidents['goaltype'] != nil
  end

  if goals.count >= 1
    first_goalscorer_player_name = goals.first['playershort'] 
  else 
    first_goalscorer_player_name = "No Goal Scorer"
  end
```

Comment: Looks much better after the edit, I updated my answer accordingly and added refactoring explanation.